# Adding item index number in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that join and groups two tables for me to get the desired results.

```
var data = (from a in cData.OrderDetails
            join b in cData.ItemMaster on a.OrderItemId equals b.ItemID
            group a by new
            {
                itemid = a.OrderItemId,
                itemname = b.ItemName
            }
            into g
            select new ConsolidatedOrder
            {
                Sno=//
                ItemName = g.Key.itemname,
                ItemQty = Convert.ToInt16(g.Sum(x => x.OrderQty))
            });
```

I also need to add a Sno inside the select statement such that it return a no starting from 1.

I know I can use a foreach then add the Sno inside the foreach statement. I kinda feel that it would be an overkill.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using method syntax for that part use the [`Select` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx) that gets both the item and the index:

```
var data = (from a in cData.OrderDetails
            join b in cData.ItemMaster on a.OrderItemId equals b.ItemID
            group a.OrderQty by new { a.OrderItemId, b.ItemName } into g
            select new {
                ItemName = g.Key.ItemName,
                ItemQty = Convert.ToInt16(g.Sum())
            }).Select((item,index) => new ConsolidatedOrder {
                Sno = index,
                ItemName = item.ItemName,
                ItemQty = item.ItemQty
            };
```

*Notice that I've changed a bit the group by and query syntax select - the items to be grouped are now only the field you desire for the `Sum`*

Comment: Thank u very Much for Your help. Trying out this throws an error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Pos.Models.ConsolidatedOrder] Select[ConsolidatedOrder,ConsolidatedOrder](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Pos.Models.ConsolidatedOrder], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[Pos.Models.ConsolidatedOrder,System.Int32,Pos.Models.ConsolidatedOrder]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @Benjohn - Add `AsEnumerable` just before the `.Select((item,index)....`

Comment: @Benjohn That's your fault because you didn't specify that you targeting EF (or LINQ to Entities) in your question.

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry My bad

Comment: @Benjohn No problem. Luckily there was easy way to extend the solution as shown by Gilad. But that's not always possible. LINQ is too broad, different query providers have their specifics, so the next time don't use simply LINQ, but concrete - EF6, EF Core (version!) etc. Happy (learning and ) coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something different. But anyways here is the solution.

```
int seNO = 1;
var data = (from a in cData.OrderDetails
....
....
select new ConsolidatedOrder
                    {
                        Sno=seNO++.ToString()
}
```